# Bash Extract 1st key of the json

Tags: bash, shell

Hi I need to extract the 1st key of the output json I've tried with different regex but didn't give expected results could you please let me to solve this.

```
      LANGUAGES=`curl  \
      --request GET \
      --header 'authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}' \
      --header 'content-type: application/string' \
      --url 'https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/languages' \
      `
      echo "$LANGUAGES" | regex
```

outputs and keys will be dynamic

```
{
    "HCL": 56543,
    "Shell": 22986,
    "Dockerfile": 307
}
```

Expected output : HCL

```
{
    "Java": 56543,
    "C++": 22986,
    "C#": 307
}
```

Expected output : Java

```
{
    "Python": 56543,
    "SHELL": 22986,
    "C": 307
}
```

Expected output : Python

Comment: have you tried `jq`

Comment: I'm very new to shell and I just tried it and worked! Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bash
echo "$LANGUAGES" | jq -r 'keys_unsorted | first'
```

Comment: Thank you so much your solution is worked! I'm very new to bash and I've been searching solution for few hours.